# Vscode: Hypersnips excention sometimes duplicates cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have the following snippet in the hypersnips extension (in vscode)

```
snippet txt "text in math" imA
\text{$1}
endsnippet
```

Usually, it works fine with me typing `txt` and it automatically sends me to

[image]

However, sometimes when using a snippet I get the following

[image]

After this occurs, if I delete that and try again, I get

[image]

This "bug" (?) occurs 10-20 per cent of the time and it is very annoying. Moreover, it is not unique to a specific snippet.

I have tried changing the version of vscode and of the extension but nothing has seemed to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Screenshot to address rioV8's comment

[image]

Comment: it is not 2 cursors but it is the next tab stop if you press TAB, you have it too if you use certain emmet abbreviations (I think they are snippets in disguise, on the fly construction)

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for the comment. It is two curses because when I write, everything gets duplicated. The position of the second cursor is on the placeholder. I have noticed that if I have multiple placeholders (=>2) this occurs (sometimes) as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is the bug of VSCode. When you overlap placeholders more than (about) 18 times, it occurs.

Just because HyperSnips adds too many placeholders, you noticed the bug.

- Test: use VSCode keybindings to add snippet (without extensions).

`ctrl+M` inserts  `$|$ |` .

[Click here to view the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeYde.gif)

However I don't know why it occurs and how to solve the problem. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Do you know how I could possibly contact vscode about this?

Comment: You can make an issue on [VSCode Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode). I have done [that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137355)  yesterday so just wait for the result. 